# Conditional probability for a RV with exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let X be a positive random variable such that for all $x,y>0$ we have that 
$$\mathbb{P}[X >x+y | X>x] = \mathbb{P}[X > y]$$

I need to show that X has exponential distribution, i.e, $\mathbb{P}[X>x]=e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x>0$. 
I was able to prove the converse statement, given that X has exponential distribution, I showed that the formula is true, which was pretty straightforward. However, I am not sure how to approach this problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Denoting $r(x)=\mathbb P[X>x]$ we have:

$$r(x+y)=\mathbb{P}\left[X>x+y\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[X>x+y\mid X>x\right]\mathbb{P}\left[X>x\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[X>y\right]\mathbb{P}\left[X>x\right]=r\left(y\right)r\left(x\right)$$

Moreover $r$ is a non increasing functions taking values in $[0,1]$.

Now have a look at the answers on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/646109/75923).

Answer (score 0):

Look at characterization (5) in the following article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function

In your case, $f(x):= \mathbb{P}(X > x)$.

To get the formula in characterization (5) you need to integrate out the conditioning in $x$ in your formula.

Of course, you will need to make appropriate modifications of characterization (5) to account for the $-\lambda$!