# find strictly increasing function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(2)=2$ and $f(x\cdot y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$ when $\gcd(x,y)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functional-equations, multiplicative-function

The problem is as in title... I understand that, according to for example answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43964/if-fxy-fxfy-then-show-that-fx-xt-for-some-t), trivial solution is $f(x)=x$. However, I don't see is weakening condition $f(x\cdot y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$ to not have to hold for all $x,y\in \mathbb{N}$, but only when $\gcd(x,y)=1$, making it possible to find any alternative solution?

Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of solutions. $f(2n)=2$ and $f(2n-1)=1$ for $n\ge1$ would be just one example.

Comment: I'm very sorry, forgot to mention an additional requirement and that is that the function has to be strictly increasing: $x>y\implies f(x)>f(y)$. I've edited the title accordingly now. Any suggestions for this case?

Comment: With that correction, I feel there will be only the "trivial" solution $f(n)=n$, but showing that will be very far from trivial.

Answer (score 3):

You can define $f(n)$ as the greatest power of $2$ that divides $n$.

Comment: $1=f(2\cdot3)\neq f(2)\cdot f(3)=2\cdot 1$

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Forgot to mention that function $f(x)$ has to be increasing, sorry.

Comment: That's *not* a minor detail!

Comment: I know, I'm very sorry for this omission.

Answer (score 0):

You can define $f(x)$ to be ***whatever you like*** in all prime powers except 2 (where it is already defined), and that would still be OK. Then use multiplicity to reconstruct $f$ in all other integer points.

- Trivial solution: $f(p^n)=p^n$.
- Solution of **Professor Vector**: $\begin{cases}f(2^n)=2,\\f(p^n)=1, p\ne2\end{cases}$
- Solution of **José Carlos Santos**: $\begin{cases}f(2^n)=2^n,\\f(p^n)=1, p\ne2\end{cases}$

There are plenty of other possibilities. How about letting $f(p^n)=n+1$ (which is consistent with $f(2)=2$)? That would be the [divisor function $\sigma_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function).

Comment: Forgot to mention that function $f(x)$ has to be increasing, sorry.