# The functional equation $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$

Tags: functional-equations

Let $f(x)$ be a function that satisfies this functional equation, $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$.

With a little bit of intuition and luck one may come to a conclusion that these are perhaps the solutions of $f(x)$,

- $f(x)=x$
- $f(x)=1$
- $f(x)=0$

However, these solutions are family solutions of $f(x)=x^n$. What I meant by this is that, when $n=1$ you get the function $f(x)=x$. When $n=0$ you get $f(x)=1$ and when $x=0$ well you get $f(x)=0$.
So, it seems $f(x)=x^n$ is the genuine solution to that functional equation and when you're taking different values for $x$ and $n$ you're getting bunch of other functions of the same family.

Getting excited by this I tried to take different values for $x$, for instance when $x=2$, $x^n$ becomes $2^n$. So, now I'm expecting the function $f(x)=2^n$ to satisfy this functional equation $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$. However, it doesn't. I don't know why it's not satisfying. May I get your explanation?

Comment: In the expression $f(x)=x^n$ the argument of the function is $x$, not $n$.  $n$ is fixed (for any specific function of the type you like).  you can't get a new solution by picking a value for $x$.

Comment: Also, there are other solutions to your functional equation, though not any other nice ones.  See, for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43964/if-fxy-fxfy-then-show-that-fx-xt-for-some-t) and its answers.

Comment: @lulu Then how do we get the solution $f(x)=0$ ?

Comment: It simply isn't true that every solution is of the form $x^n$.  for some $n$.  $0$ isn't of that form and, as I mentioned, there are discontinuous solutions as well.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of @greedoid's proposed original. The original functional equation is the same, but the answers there don't (for good reason) address the particular confusion the OP has here.

Comment: What is the domain of $x$? There are quite a few [completely multiplicative functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function) out there ...

Answer (score 0):

If you take the equation
$$ \tag{*} f(x) = x^n $$
and "set $x=0$", what you get is *not* $f(x)=0$, but
$$ f(0) = 0^n $$
which does not define a function -- it only says what the function value must be at $0$ (and doesn't even do that until you decide what $n$ is).

As @lulu pointed out in comments, your assumption that every solution of the functional equation must have the form $\text{(*)}$ is **simply not true**. $f(x)=0$ does not have this form, and there is an infinity of "wild" discontinuous solutions too (at least if we assume the Axiom of Choice).

Answer (score -1):

We may prove that the non-identical function $f(x)$ which is continuous over $(0,+\infty)$ and satisfies $$f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$$ is $$f(x)=x^\alpha$$ only.