# Find $f(1986)$ if $f(1)=1$ and $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) - 2f(xy)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

> If $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) - 2f(xy)$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$ and $f(1) = 1$, compute $f(1986)$.

---

I found that $f(2)=0$ and I could just plug in numbers from there on, but I can't think of an efficient way to solve this problem. Could someone please solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Try a few more and look for a pattern.

Comment: @vadim123  I found that $f(x)=1$ when $x$ is an odd number, but $f(x)=0$ when $x$ is an even number.  So is the answer $0$?

Comment: Do you mean, "suppose this is true for all $x,y$?" Because it reads like you are saying for one particular pair $x,y$. Also "let" is usually used when defining something, rather than when stating a condition. "Assume $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)-2f(xy)$" is more what you want.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - Ok.

Comment: You probably mean "solve the functional equation", where $f(x)$ is defined for any real $x$. Is it possible we need more assumptions, besides $f$ being non-constant?

Comment: Compare with [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368414/functional-equation-fxy-fxfyfxfy).

Comment: FWIW, $f(x+1)=f(1)-f(x)$

Comment: And hence $f(x+2)=f(x)$.

Comment: On the other hand, $f(x) = f(x+2) = f(x) + f(2) - 2f(2x)$

Comment: $f(0) = 0$ and $f(-x) = -f(x)$

Comment: And $f(2)=f(1+1)=f(1)+f(1)-2f(1)=0$

Comment: Off the top of my head there may not nesc. be one answer.  If f is not continuous I don't think we can determine any values for irrational x.  (I imagine given an $f(x)$ we can inductively deduce f(xQ) and we can probably deduce f(Q) from f(1) but f(x) can be set to anything we like).  That's off the top of my head.  If f is continuous though that forces the irrational values.

Comment: @fleablood, vadim123's answer shows there is no answer except for the constant function $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Yeah, that seems undeniable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $x=y=0$, we find $f(0)=0$.
With $y=1$, we find $f(x+1)=f(1)-f(x)$, so $f(x+2)=f(1)-(f(1)-f(x))=f(x)$ and by induction $f(x+2n)=f(x)$. In particular, $$f(1986)=f(0+2\cdot 993)=f(0)=0. $$

*Remark:* The property that $f(1)=1$ was not needed.

Answer (score 8):

Taking $y=1$ we get $$f(x+1)=f(x)+f(1)-2f(x)=f(1)-f(x)$$
In particular, taking $x=0$ in the above gives $f(1)=f(1)-f(0)$, so $f(0)=0$.
Taking $x+1$ for $x$, we get $$f(x+2)=f(1)-f(x+1)=f(1)-(f(1)-f(x))=f(x)$$
Hence the function is periodic with period $2$.

Now, taking $y=2$ we get $$f(x)=f(x+2)=f(x)+f(2)-2f(2x)$$ 
which gives $$2f(2x)=f(2)$$
However, $f(2)=f(0)=0$.  So $f(2x)=0$ for all $x$, and the only solution is the constant $$f(x)=0$$

Comment: @vadim123 - $f$ is not constant.

Comment: @H.S., it does not appear that a non-constant $f$ is possible.

Comment: Actually you could get $f(0)$ more directly by calculating $f(0+0)$.

Comment: Um, there's no reason in your reasoning that $f(2k) = 0$ and $f(2k + 1) = c$ for some other constant.

Comment: @fleablood, $f(2x)=0$ for all $x$, not just for integers.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yeah.  that follows.  It seems there is no non constant.