# A function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfies equation $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb R $

Tags: derivatives

> **Problem**: A function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfies equation $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$ and $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.
> If $f'(0)=2$, find $f'(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$
>
> **Solution**:
> $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$
> Differentiating partially w.r.t $x$ we get
> $f'(x+y)=f'(x)f(y)$
> At x=0
> $f'(y)=f'(0)f(y)$
> $f'(y)= 2f(y)$
> $f'(x)= 2f(x)$

Can we solve  question like above ?

I mean,$f'(x)$ represent ordinary diff. while I used it for partial diff.

Comment: $f(x) = e^{2x}$

Comment: @Ethan According to your function my ans is correct. But Is method correct ??

Comment: Do not use full stop for multiplication. Especially when it's not even necessary. If you absolutely must use a symbol to indicate multiplication, use `\cdot`.

Comment: Also, no. You cannot do this. You are only told that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. You must *prove* that $f$ is everywhere differentiable for your argument to go through.

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38376/classifying-functions-of-the-form-fxy-fxfy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a name for function with the exponential property $f(x+y)=f(x) \cdot f(y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22069/is-there-a-name-for-function-with-the-exponential-property-fxy-fx-cdot-f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More technically, you can't do like that(why?)

Since you are not given that $f$ is differentiable(except at $0$), therefore you can't take derivatives on both sides. So, first you need to check if $f$ is differentiable and in that process, you'll get $f'(x)$( if $f$ comes out to be differentiable on some non-empty set of $\Bbb R$)

Note, $f(0+0)=f(0)f(0)\implies f(0)=0,1$ but $f(x)\neq 0$ for any $x\in \Bbb R\implies f(0)=1$

Then, $1=f(0)=f(x-x)=f(x).f(-x)\implies f(-x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$

Now,
$$R.H.D.=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)f(h)-f(x)}{h}$$ $$=f(x)\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(h)-1}{h}\tag{1}$$

similarly, $$L.H.D.=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(x)f(-h)}{h}$$ $$=f(x)\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1-\frac{1}{f(h)}}{h}=f(x)\left(\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(h)-1}{h}\right)\left(\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1}{f(h)}\right)=f(x)\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(h)-1}{h}\tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, $L.H.D.=R.H.D.\implies f$ is differential.

Then, $$f'(x)=f(x)\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(h)-1}{h}$$

Since, $2=f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(h)-1}{h}$

Therefore, $$f'(x)=2f(x)\tag{QED}$$

Comment: your answer looks much better