# Show that if $f(1)=1$, then there exists a constant $\alpha$ such that $f(x)=x^\alpha$ for all $x \in (0, +\infty)$.

Tags: analysis

Let $f: (0, +\infty) \to\mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y \in (0, +\infty)$.

Show that if $f(1)=1$, then there exists a constant $\alpha$ such that $f(x)=x^\alpha$ for all $x \in (0, +\infty)$.

So far:
$$f(x^\alpha)=f(\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{\alpha\text{ times}})=\underbrace{f(x)\cdot f(x)\cdots f(x)}_{\alpha\text{ times}}=\alpha\cdot f(x)$$
Hence, $f(x^\alpha)=\alpha\cdot f(x)$.

From here I am not quite sure, but I believe I need to differentiate both sides, then move all terms to one side equaling zero and solve?

Comment: The "alpha times" twice is supposed to be under the first sentence.

Comment: Your suggestion really does not work: Say that $\alpha=\pi$. What do you mean by $f(x)$ times itself $\pi$ times?

Comment: OK, then I am at a loss.

Comment: What property does the $\log$ of your function have?

Comment: Are you referring to ln(xy)=ln(x)+ln(y)?

Comment: AKA L(xy)=L(x)+L(y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $f(y) > 0$(Why?). Now let $g(x) = \ln(f(a^x))$, where $a>0$. We then have
$$g(x+y) = \ln(f(a^{x+y})) = \ln(f(a^xa^y)) = \ln(f(a^x) f(a^y)) = g(x) + g(y)$$
This is the [Cauchy function equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) and if $g(x)$ is continuous, the solution is
$$g(x) = cx$$
Hence, we have
$$f(a^x) = e^{cx} \implies f(x) = x^t$$
Note that in the above proof, we only relied on the continuity of $f$.

Below are some similar problems based on Cauchy function equation:

[Is there a name for function with the exponential property $f(x+y)=f(x) \cdot f(y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22069/)

[Classifying Functions of the form $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38376/)

[If $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f (x + y) = f (x) f (y)$ and continuous at $0$, then continuous everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151032/)

[continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ such that $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141293/)

[What can we say about functions satisfying $f(a + b) = f(a)f(b) $ for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152944/)

Comment: But my problem states that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y \in (0, +\infty)$.  Not that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y \in (0, +\infty)$.  Sorry, I edited my comment I had the + sign in the wrong place.  Also, where is the use of $f(1)=1$?

Comment: @user113009 Where did I use $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$. I only used $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$. Kindly read the proof completely.

Comment: @user113009 Where did I use $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$? Why don't you read my answer completely from the first line and see if you follow?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to understand why the $g(x+y)=...=g(x)+g(y)$.  Is it just to get that g(x)=cx?  Also, I am not seeing where f(1)=1 was used.  Was it used to get $f(a^x) = e^{cx} \implies f(x) = x^t$

Comment: @user113009 $f(1)=1$, was used in the very first step, to conclude that $f(x) \neq 0$. Note that if $f(1) = b \neq 1$, we would then get $f(x\cdot 1) = f(x) \cdot f(1) = bf(x) \implies f(x) = 0$, since $b \neq 1$. Hence, for non-trivial $f(x)$, we need $f(1) = 1$.

Comment: @user113009 Which step is unclear in $g(x+y) = \cdots = g(x) + g(y)$?

Comment: First, thanks for the clarification on the $f(1)=1$ use. All the steps are clear but, I do not understand why we need it unless it is to obtain that $g(x)=cx$.

Comment: @user113009 Yes, we need it to obtain $g(x) = cx$. The reason we want to obtain $g(x) = cx$ is that, we can then obtain $f(x) = x^t$ as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I wanted to make sure I fully understood the solution. :-)

Comment: @user113009 No problem. Feel free to ask.