# Prove that $f'$ exists for all $x$ in $R$ if $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and $f'(0)$ exists

Tags: analysis, derivatives, functional-equations

A function $f$ is defined in $R$, and $f'(0)$ exist.
Let $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ then prove that $f'$ exists for all $x$ in $R$.

I think I have to use two fact:
$f'(0)$ exists
$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$
How to combine these two things to prove that statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64766/solution-for-exponential-functions-functional-equation-by-using-a-definition-of

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175607/differentiable-function-not-constant-fxy-fxfy-f0-2

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151032/if-f-colon-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-such-that-f-x-y-f-x-f-y-an

Answer (score 6):

We have $$f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)f(0)=f^2(0)\Rightarrow f(0)=0\text{ or }f(0)=1$$
If $f(0)=1$ by definition
$$f^{\prime}(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-1}{h}$$
and so
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)f(h)-f(x)}{h}=f(x)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-1}{h}=f(x)f^{\prime}(0)$$
Thus $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$

If $f(0)=0$, $f(x)=f(x+0)=0\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and again $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: what's missing is just proving that $f(0)=1$.

Comment: @tst I am editing it.

Comment: You mean $f'(x)$ in the second line?

Comment: It's a bit easier, $f(x)=f(x+0)=f(x)f(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is continuous at $x=0$ and hence show that $f$ is continuous at the whole set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ and hence is of the form $e^{ax}$.

Comment: You make quite a stronger statement than what was asked for, but it's technically correct.