# $f(a+b,\lambda) = f (a,\lambda) \cdot f(b,\lambda)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functional-equations

Consider the equation:

$f(a+b,\lambda) = f (a,\lambda) \cdot f(b,\lambda)$, for $a \geq 0$ and $b \geq 0$.

Is my understanding that this simple functional equation is important in analysis. Can someone give me examples where this can be used in practice, its theoretical importance and maybe some literature where I can find more?

Also, if $f(\cdot,\lambda)$ is continuous, then one can show that $f(a,\lambda) =$exp$(ag(\lambda))$, for some function $g(\lambda)$. Is this the only type of function that will satisfy the equation above?

Comment: $f=0$ seem to be solution too ...

Comment: Of relevance is [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22069) (which provides a solution for fixed $\lambda$).

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Thank you!

Comment: @wece: It seams to me that is either zero for all $x$, or it is of the type exp$(ag(\lambda)$.

Comment: Since nothing happens to $\lambda$, set $g(x)\equiv f(x,\lambda)$ and you see that this is the exact same question as in Lord_Farin's comment. The solution there is $g(x)=\text e^{c x}$, hence you have the "pullback" $f(x,\lambda)=\text e^{c_\lambda x}$

Comment: yep really good link ...

Comment: @Cherufe Is there anything else you'd like to know or can this question be closed as a duplicate of the referenced one? (The second answer there provides some perspective on the uses/theoretical importance in analysis.)

Comment: @Lord_Farin
The link was explanatory enough :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a name for function with the exponential property $f(x+y)=f(x) \times f(y)$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22069/is-there-a-name-for-function-with-the-exponential-property-fxy-fx-times-f)