# Is this differentiability question solvable?

Tags: functions, derivatives

> Let $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.
>
> Suppose that $f(3)=3$ then $f'(3)$ is equal to?

Normally, what I'd do is partially differentiate wrt $x$.
$$f'(x+y)=f'(x)f(y)$$
On substituting $y=3$, $x=0$, we get $$f'(3)=3f'(0)$$
But we don't know the value of $f'(0)$, nor of any other $f'(x)$.

So is this question solvable? If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: The only continuous functions $f$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ are of the form $f(x)=a^{x}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22069/is-there-a-name-for-function-with-the-exponential-property-fxy-fx-cdot-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put $f'(0) = a$. Then, we obtain
$$
f'(x) = a f(x),
$$
for all $x \in {\mathbb R}$. Therefore,
$$
{\mathrm e^{ax}}\left({\mathrm e^{-ax}}f(x) \right)' = 0,
$$
and because ${\mathrm e}^{ax} \neq 0$,
$$
{\mathrm e^{-ax}}f(x) = C,
$$
where $C$ is a constant. With $f(3) = 3$, we get
$$
f(x) = 3{\mathrm e}^{-3a}{\mathrm e}^{ax}.
$$
However, as $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y \in {\mathbb R}$, $3{\mathrm e}^{-3a}$ must be $1$ . Therefore, $f(x) = 3^{x/3}$, and $f'(3) = \log 3$.